# Marklogic -How to add the collection name in cts:uris

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

Query:

```
let $collection := "sampledata"

for $uri1 in cts:uris((),(),( 
cts:element-query(xs:QName("root"),
cts:and-query((
cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("root"),xs:QName($value1),$value2),
cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("root"),xs:QName($value3),$value4),
cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("year"),$value5),
cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("month"),$value6),
cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("num"),xs:QName("value"),$value7)
)))) )

return $uri1
```

How to add the collection name in above mentioned xquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cts:collection-query()`, as in:

```
cts:and-query((
    cts:collection-query("sampledata"),
    cts:element-query(...)
    ))
```

See:

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:collection-query

By the way, when just returning the uri, there's no need the for/return iteration.  The result is the same as just returning `cts:uris()`.

Hoping that helps,